# NextJS how to avoid Image warnings

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm getting a warning for almost all of the local images in my site:

```
Image with src "http://localhost:3000/_next/static/media/icon_home.0f967506.svg" has either width or height modified, but not the other. If you use CSS to change the size of your image, also include the styles 'width: "auto"' or 'height: "auto"' to maintain the aspect ratio.
```

Even when I'm letting `NextJS` just infer the size, as they suggest to:

```
<div className="flex aspect-square w-10 justify-center md:w-12">
    <Image src={link.icon} alt={link.title} />
</div>
```

I saw some threads related to the same warning, but they all end up suggesting to use `fill` or to set the size with `TailwindCSS` classes, but I'd like to avoid specifying any size at all, as I understand that's the whole point of using `Image` + local resource, since it's able to calculate the size of the `.png` (which actually works great)

**Is there any workaround to get rid of the warning without specifying size properties?**

Comment: I'm applying `width` and `height` values but still getting this warning. So I think there is a  problem with nextjs. Please post an update if you found a solution.

Comment: @HamedSiaban as for me, setting `width` and `height` classnames removes the warning, but of course that misses the whole point of `Image` wrapper autosizing.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding w-auto to your Image component:

```
<div className="flex aspect-square w-10 justify-center md:w-12">
    <Image className="w-auto" src={link.icon} alt={link.title} />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @HamedSiaban, unfortunately `w-auto` makes the image fill the container

Answer (score 0):

You can try disabling server-side rendering (SSR) when rendering the image using the `React-No-SSR` Package .
first install : `npm install react-no-ssr`

then wrap the Image with `<NoSSR>`  :

```
 <NoSSR>
      <Image src={link.icon} alt={link.title} />
    </NoSSR>
```

make sure to import  : `import NoSSR from 'react-no-ssr';`

Comment: Thank you @monim, not exactly what I was looking for, but didn't know the package and looks interesting for other purposes :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding priority to your Image

> 

```
<Image priority src={link.icon} alt={link.title} />
```